# Unable to scrape the emails by using the code?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Here is the code, it is showing the error, and not scraping out the emails, I want to scrape the emails of a particular topic eg rental cars and want to modify it for that

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import json
import requests


with open('test.txt') as fp:
   line = fp.readline()
   while line:
        page = line.strip()
        reqs = Request(page, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'})
        html_page = urlopen(reqs).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
        links = []
        #print("\n")
        #print(line.strip())
        for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
            links.append(link.get('href'))
        for link in links:
            req = Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'})
            html_page = urlopen(req).read()
            #html_page = urlopen(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
            #soup = html_page.read().decode('utf-8')
            #print("\n")
            if(len(re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", str(soup))) > 0):
                for i in set(re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", str(soup))):
                    with open('emails_scrap.txt', 'a') as f: 
                        f.write(i + "\n")


        line = fp.readline()
```

Comment: Welcome To StackOverflow, What makes you unable to scrap? Is there any error or smth? If there is, please include it in the question

Comment: Actually , i want to scrap emails related to a particular topic eg rental cars. and with this code , and instead of headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'} , i want to use google chrome , so that i can use the VPN and scrap emails from USA only .